# Ruby on Rails, mysql column type :text, What class is this as a ruby object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

你好，

When a column in mysql table is typed :text, how is this then treated in Ruby.

In other words, what is the class?

Is it a string?

Comment: This will explain: http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN|en|你好%0A

Comment: Sorry, that link wont' work.

你好 is Mandarin for hello "nihao"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is a 'String'.

Comment: >> c.content
=> "sdfsdf"
>> c.content.class
=> String
hehe silly question